# CSS overlayed rgba transpanrency

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
           background:rgba(0,255,255,0.3);
        }
        #div1 {
           width:300px;
           height:300px;           
        }
        #div2 {
           width:200px;
           height:200px;          
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div><br/>
</body>
```

what is the actually computed transparency of div2? I am confused. It is a unknown number that is not 0.3+0.3 or 0.3+0.3*0.3

Comment: Looks like 0.51, but i have no idea how to calculate it: http://jsfiddle.net/rf3p1yLg/1/

Comment: check your developer console?

Answer (score 6):

The sum of alpha channels can be calculated as:

> alpha_top + alpha_bottom * (1 - alpha_top) =
>   0.3 + 0.3 * (1 - 0.3) =
>   0.3 + 0.3 * 0.7 =
>   0.3 + 0.21 =
>   **0.51**

For more explanation, see [Alpha Compositing @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), which lists the formula as:

> [image: formula]

or

> [image: formula]

This is essentially the same formula [used by Bogdan Kuštan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011297/css-overlayed-rgba-transpanrency#answer-31012350) and it can also be found in [this answer by bwoebi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906525/how-do-you-calculate-overlapping-rgba-values#answer-16906609).

Comment: really clear answer. helps a lot thank you very much

Comment: @jinxinni If this answer solved your issue, please accept it in order to close the issue. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have applied opacity in `div{}` then this would be `.3` for `#div1{}` and `.3 * .3 = .09` for `#div2{}` as #div1 has opacity value `.3` and #div2 also use opacity but is currently holding `.3` so it's going to be multiplied for children.

Comment: I tried it in photoshop and i was able to get the same color using 51% as the opacity

Comment: Did you try using opacity .3 on first layer and .3 on second layer? This will be similar as you wrote in css. But effectively, 51% may find the color as css too.

Comment: sorry, I can't check link. Try what I say in photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

its

(0.3 + 0.3) - (0.3 * 0.3) = 0.51

First You need to add overlapping transparency values, and subtract their multiplication. Why? I don't know. I don't event know how I know it, it just one of those things like letter spacing from PhotoShop to CSS, You need to divide PS value from 1000, and You get value in `ems`. Sorry for offtopic.